# Converting Sequence Diagram to Java code

Tags: java, uml

My teacher assigned an exercise which consists in translating (in the best possible way) a sequence diagram to Java code.

This is the sequence diagram:

[image]

And this is my attempt at solving this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Seminar {
    private int getMark() {
        return calculateMark();
    }

    private int calculateMark() {
        return 10;
    }
}

class Student {
    private List<Seminar> _seminars = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Seminar> getSeminars() {
        return _seminars;
    }
}

class TranscriptBuilder {
    public void New(Student student) {

    }
}
```

But I couldn't finish `TranscriptBuilder` as I couldn't find anything about `<<system>>` and what it means. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<system>>` is a sterotype in UML :

A stereotype defines how an existing metaclass may be extended, and enables the use of platform or domain specific terminology or notation in place of, or in addition to, the ones used for the extended metaclass.

I think here it refers to the core system where you need to implement a method to print the `Student` information.

I suggest you `@Override` the `toString()` method in `Student` then implement a `print()` method in `SharedServices` as indicated in your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the guts of the TranscriptBuilder constructor, particularly, getting the seminars and doing the loop as in the diagram.

```
TranscriptBuilder(Student s) {
    List<Seminar> sems = s.getSeminars();
    for (Seminar sem : sems)
        sem.getMark();
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be in new() method?

Comment: Well yea. It's called a constructor though; it is a"special" method that instantiates a class.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'system' is an Actor stereotyped 'system'.

All actors are external to your system definition. They are humans or other software systems interacting with your software.

You will not implement the printer, you will only use its API to print the result.